# can't use JOIN with generate_series on Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

generate_series function on Redshift works as expected, when used in a simple select statement.

```
WITH series AS (
    SELECT n as id from generate_series (-10, 0, 1) n
) SELECT * FROM series;
-- Works fine
```

As soon as I add a JOIN condition, redshift throws

> com.amazon.support.exceptions.ErrorException: Function
>   generate_series(integer,integer,integer)" not supported"

```
DROP TABLE testing;
CREATE TABLE testing (
  id INT
);
WITH series AS (
  SELECT n as id from generate_series (-10, 0, 1) n
) SELECT * FROM series S JOIN testing T ON S.id = T.id;
-- Function "generate_series(integer,integer,integer)" not supported.
```

Redshift Version

```
SELECT version();
-- PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.1485
```

Are there any workarounds to make this work?

Answer (score 4):

`generate_series` is not supported by Redshift. It works only standalone on a leader node.

A workaround would be using `row_number` against any table that has sufficient number of rows:

```
with 
series as (
    select (row_number() over ())-11 from some_table limit 10
) ...
```

also, this question was asked multiple times already

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that this does not work on Redshift. 
See [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-functions.html).

The easiest workaround is to create a permanent table "manually" beforehand with the values within that table, e.g. you could have rows on that table for -1000 to +1000, then select the range from that table,

So for your example you would have something like

```
WITH series AS (
  SELECT n as id from (select num as n from newtable where num between -10 and 0) n
) SELECT * FROM series S JOIN testing T ON S.id = T.id;
```

Does that work for you?

Alternatively, if you cannot create the table beforehand or prefer not to, you could use something like this

```
with ten_numbers as (select 1 as num union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9 union select 0)
,generted_numbers AS
(
    SELECT (1000*t1.num) + (100*t2.num) + (10*t3.num) + t4.num-5000 as gen_num
    FROM ten_numbers AS t1
      JOIN ten_numbers AS t2 ON 1 = 1
      JOIN ten_numbers AS t3 ON 1 = 1
      JOIN ten_numbers AS t4 ON 1 = 1
)
select  gen_num from generted_numbers
where gen_num between -10 and 0
order by 1;
```